# React Native - Headless JS example

Tags: react-native

The react native documentation about this seems more than incomplete. I was following this guide which doesn't seem to lead me anywhere:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/headless-js-android.html#headless-js

Where am I supposed to put the .java file?
How am I supposed to start the task?

Comment: I am actually solving this at the moment too. Have you got any progress yet? I think that you can start the task with this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appregistry.html#startheadlesstask

Comment: No. I implemented a native module with a background service for Android. This was fairly straight-forward. I will try it again at some point and post my findings here.

Comment: Care to share this Android service you did? Because I did something similar :D

Comment: @Alex Did you manage to integrate react native in a headless way? Did my answer help you setting this up?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you did. I'm new to native Android dev and I followed the docs, but they didn't work for me. Turns out I misunderstood and thought that I can start the actual task FROM my react native code.  It doesn't work that way, though.  You write the JavaScript code you want to run when the task is started, but you need to start that task from native code.  So, steps you did already are setting up the task, but nothing is telling them to start.

I'll use my project as an example:

In my JavaScript:

```
    /* 
      This code basically registers WHAT javascript code
      I want to call when the 'disconnect' service is started
    */

    const disconnectTask = () => async () => {
      if (connectionIsActive) {
        user.goOffline();
      }
    };

    AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('disconnect', disconnectTask);
```

Then I created the java file here:

projectroot/android/app/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/ForceOfflineService.java

```
package com.mycompany.app;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.jstasks.HeadlessJsTaskConfig;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class ForceOfflineService extends HeadlessJsTaskService {
  @Override
  @Nullable
  protected HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
      Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
      // WritableMap data = extras != null ? Arguments.fromBundle(extras) : null;
      
      // ---- EDIT ---- the line above no longer works, since null is not an accepted value anymore.
      WritableMap data = extras != null ? Arguments.fromBundle(extras) : Arguments.createMap();

      // Make sure that the string below ("disconnect" in this case)
      // matches the string used to register the task in your JS

      return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
              "disconnect",
              data,
              5000);
  }
}
```

then inside your android manifest
(mine is here: projectroot/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)
you must register the service inside the application tag

```
<manifest>
  <application>

    <!-- other existing configuration -->

    <service android:name=".ForceOfflineService" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Lastly, you need to use the native code to start the service.  In my MainActivity.kt I start the service when the onStop lifecycle hook is called:

```
 override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()

    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(Runnable {
      val service = Intent(applicationContext, ForceOfflineService::class.java)
      applicationContext.startService(service)
    }, IDLE_TIME_BEFORE_DISCONNECT)
  }
```

and that's it!

Answer (score -1):

Put the .java file into your project. E.g. `/app/src/main/java/com/alex/app/service/`

When you want to execute specific JavaScript code without showing a `ReactRootView` you can use your custom `HeadlessJsTaskService`.

To start the task just call `startService(new Intent(this, MyTaskService.class));` for example from another service or even from an activity.

Hint:
I changed the `getTaskConfig()` method of the tutorial, so it allows empty extras:

```
@Override
@Nullable
protected HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    WritableMap data = extras != null ? Arguments.fromBundle(extras) : null;
    return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
            "SomeTaskName",
            data,
            5000);
}
```

Or at least change it, so it does not just silently fail if no extras are provided.

Comment: Can you please add more detail its still unclear that how to actually use headless js for beginners