# Can I call a function inside a class using Headless JS? React-Native android

Tags: java, android, react-native, background-process, headless

I cannot find any proper documentation for implementing Headless JS in React-Native for android.

As, for now I have implemented these:

**AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
<service android:name="com.axcesscarlock.MyTaskService" />
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;
```

**I  created a java class:**

```
package com.locationlistener.service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.jstasks.HeadlessJsTaskConfig;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class MyTaskService extends HeadlessJsTaskService {

  @Override
  protected @Nullable HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
      return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
          "SomeTaskName",
          Arguments.fromBundle(extras),
          10000, // timeout for the task
          false // optional: defines whether or not  the task is allowed in foreground. Default is false
        );
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

**And this code in a javascript file:**

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('SomeTaskName', () => require('SomeTaskName'));

module.exports = async (taskData) => {
    console.log('Hello from the background');
};
```

I need to run a function when the user sends the app to the background, but that function relates (calls) other functions and data from the state. So, in this case, should I call the entire class when in the background? 
Currently using the posted code, I am having this error saying "Unable to resolve module SomeTaskName".

Comment: I just answered a question similar to this.  Hopefully this can help you some:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66610560/1414170

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that someTaskName file is in the same directory.

and edit

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('SomeTaskName', () => require('./SomeTaskName'));
```

---

Were you able to use headless js? I try to apply it too, but my application crashes. Although I do everything as described in the documentation